# Play Audio Through Speakers with Headphones Plugged In

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I want to play an audio file through speakers with plugged-in headset.

I tried the following:
MainActivity.java:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)mainActivity
     .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(mainActivity, R.raw.chime);
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
mp.start();
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

But the audio is still played through the plugged in headphones. How can I direct the audio output to the speakers, with plugged in headphones, correctly?

**EDIT 1:**

I tried the following code from the post [Android, how to route the audio to speakers when headphones inserted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429701/android-how-to-route-the-audio-to-speakers-when-headphones-inserted):

```
   MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(mainActivity, R.raw.chime);
   AudioManager am = (AudioManager) mainActivity.getSystemService(mainActivity.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    try {
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException| IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        Log.i("TAG","Error is " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    am.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
    mp.start();
```

But I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalStateException

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, how to route the audio to speakers when headphones inserted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429701/android-how-to-route-the-audio-to-speakers-when-headphones-inserted)

Comment: Thanks very much @GreyBeardedGeek , I tried the code in the post you suggested, but still cannot get it to work. Any other ideas how to play the audio through speakers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll provide a complete code snippet (tested on Android 24), which I had to aggregate from multiple hints to solutions:

```
public class AudioClass
{
    AudioManager audioManager;
    Activity activity;

    public AudioClass(Activity activity)
    {
       this.activity = activity;

        //NEEDS TO BE DONE BEFORE PLAYING AUDIO!
        audioManager = (AudioManager)
            activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    }

    public void playAudio() {
        //CAN BE CALLED FROM ANYWHERE AFTER AudioClass IS INSTANTIATED
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.audio_file_name);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

And the permissions for modifying audio settings need to be set in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```